# Watir's browser.refresh gives "Access denied"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am exploring Watir in my project. It works perfectly when trying a URL for the first time, but when I navigate to another URL or even I just refresh the existing Watir's browser (by command and manual refresh) it says **ACCESS DENIED** `Please verify you are a human`.

I Have googled for this and added Headless in my code but that did not work.

This is what I am trying in my rails console:

```
# Headless initialized and started
> headless = Headless.new
> headless.start

# Watir object initialized and navigated
> browser = Watir::Browser.new
> browser.goto 'https://www.pepboys.com/'

# Typed `browser` in console, got the output
> browser

`WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchAlertError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..f80f33b9a75f7d034 url="https://www.pepboys.com/" title="**Pep Boys Tires, Auto Parts, Auto Repair & Service and Car Accessories**">`

# Now when refreshing `browser`

> browser.refresh

# Typed `browser` in console, got the output

> browser

`WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchAlertError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..f80f33b9a75f7d034 url="https://www.pepboys.com/" title="**Access to this page has been denied.**">`
```

Both `browser` has different **title** where one is giving the site's title and another one is giving Access denied message.

Please, can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here or missing anything?

Comment: Sounds like your regular Captcha protection. You can take a screenshot with `browser.screenshot.save('screenshot.png')` and see what the page looks like.

Comment: @Casper Yes, this is the main reason, it says *Please verify you are a human*  is there any way I can overcome this thing? I tried it without Headless there I was already getting the Captcha error.